# How to stage and push multiple apps to a single repo in GITHUB

Tags: git, github

I am writing a react blog with architecture like this:

```
  Parent-Dir ------>client (create-react-app frontend)
        |              package.json
        |
        |
        V
      server (Node/Express backend)
         package.json
```

Now my issue is I am not sure how to push this in a single github repository.

I tried doing an 'npm install' on the Parent-Dir, so that i could bundle everything together. But it throws an error:

saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/tyuyut/package.json'

So, how can i push multiple directories in a single github repo. I am a complete noob in Git, so please don't shy away from even correcting my basic assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Only run `npm install` in a directory that has package.json in it. In your case, run `npm install` in the client or server folder.

Comment: i actually did a git init on Parent-Dir which helped

Comment: yep. git init will help if you want to do git operation in the folder, but not npm.